# How can I number the references in a bibliography irrespective of their order of appearance in a document?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, formatting, numbering

I'm putting together a linguistics bibliography using `lsalike.bib` and `lsalike.sty`. I'm generating it by using `\nocite{*}` and would like the references to be numbered (but kept in the usual order).

I'm fairly new to LaTeX, but here's my attempt at a MWE. This is as close as I've been able to get so far.

Document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lsalike}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{\@arabic\c@enumi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{lsalike}
\bibliography{mwe-bib}
\end{document}
```

Bibliography file:

```
@phdthesis{Nossalik:2009aa,
    Author = {Larissa Nossalik},
    School = {McGill University},
    Title = {L2 Acquisition of {R}ussian Aspect},
    Year = {2009}
    }

 @article{Bermel:1995aa,
    Author = {Neil Bermel},
    Journal = {{R}ussian {L}inguistics},
    Number = {3},
    Pages = {333--348},
    Title = {Aspect and the Shape of Action in {O}ld {R}ussian},
    Volume = {19},
    Year = {1995}
    }
```

This gives me a list of references with a `0` before each one. Is there a way to display `1` before the first reference in the list, `2` before the second, et c.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `lsalike` package is meant to do author-year citations:

> The "lsalike" bibliography style (lsalike.bst) creates citations 
>   with labels like
>
> ```
>   \citeauthoryear{author-info}{year}
> ```
>
> These labels are processed by the following commands: [...]

So the bibliography is meant not to have numbers. If you'd like to have numbers anyway, you can do a different patch:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\setlength}{\usecounter{enumiv}\setlength}{}{}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{\stepcounter{enumiv}[\arabic{enumiv}]}
\makeatother
```

The numbers will appear in the margin.

[image]

With Guido's suggestion the numbers can be pushed inside the margin:

```
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{\stepcounter{enumiv}\hspace{\bighang}[\arabic{enumiv}] }
```

Comment: To avoid the numbers appearing in the margin use `\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{\hspace{\bibhang}\stepcounter{enumiv}\arabic{enumiv}. }` @egreg Wouldn't it be better to define a new counter instead using `enumiv`?

Comment: Thanks @egreg, this is exactly what I was trying to do. @Guido, when I try your edit, I get an `Undefined control sequence` error regarding the `\bighang` command. Do I need to load another package for this?

Comment: Woops, figured it out. `\bibhang`, not `\bighang`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how fixed you are to this `lsalike` style, but with `biblatex` this would be a quite simple task:

```
\begin{filecontents}{mwe-bib.bib}
@phdthesis{Nossalik:2009aa,
    Author = {Larissa Nossalik},
    School = {McGill University},
    Title = {L2 Acquisition of {R}ussian Aspect},
    Year = {2009}
    }

 @article{Bermel:1995aa,
    Author = {Neil Bermel},
    Journal = {{R}ussian {L}inguistics},
    Number = {3},
    Pages = {333--348},
    Title = {Aspect and the Shape of Action in {O}ld {R}ussian},
    Volume = {19},
    Year = {1995}
    }

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{lsalike}
\usepackage[
    sorting=nyt,
    style=numeric,
    backend=bibtex,
]{biblatex}

%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{\@arabic\c@enumi}
%\makeatother

\bibliography{mwe-bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Nossalik:2009aa}
\cite{Bermel:1995aa}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

%\bibliographystyle{lsalike}
%\bibliography{mwe-bib}
\end{document}
```

And I think adapting the biblatex style to fit the lsalike style might be much easier than introducing some weird counters into a existing bibliography style

Answer (score 2):

A solution alternative to that proposed by `@egeg` is

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{lsaref}
\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\@lbibitem}{\stepcounter{lsaref}\arabic{lsaref}.}{}{}
\makeatother
```