# Completely lost with BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, characters

I'm new to LaTeX, and have managed to transfer an essay I'd written in Word into LaTeX fairly satisfactorily, but I'm now trying to sort out the bibliography using BibTeX and I'm completely lost. I have a number of questions.

Should I be using BibTeX or BibLaTeX?

What do I need to put into my LaTeX document and where (i.e. in the preamble or where the bibliography should go)?

I want to use a special bibliography style called `lsalike`. There are two files, one `.bst` and one `.sty` - do I need both of these or just the `.bst` and where do I put them? (I'm using OS X/a MacBook and TeXShop.) How do I use this style in LaTeX? I believe the style will have small caps for the authors' names (though I can't confirm as I've not got it working yet!) - how do I turn this feature off?

How do I get special symbols in BibTeX entries? (A number of the authors have 'foreign' characters in their names, as do some of the titles.)

Sorry for so many questions and ones that have no doubt been answered before, but I could really do with some help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. You should have a look at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib.

Comment: What is this bibtex style? I couldn't find it on the we: the search gives things like "is a like" (in 3 words)!

Comment: Hi Bernard, see here: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=lsalike

Comment: Thanks Jubobs, although I'm still pretty clueless!

Comment: Do you want to see how a simple document would look using `lsalike.bst` and `lsalike.sty`?

Comment: That would be useful, @jon!

Comment: I think @Bernard has provided a good link to an example of how to use it, so I won't reduplicate it here unless there is a follow-up question about some detail about usage.  As for where you'd put the `.sty` and the `.bst`, on a Unix-like system (Linux, Mac, etc.) with TeX Live, you should be able to run this command: `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME`.  It will give you the 'base' of your personal `texmf` directory.  Then `mkdir -p <BASE>/{bibtex/bst/lsalike,tex/latex/lsalike}` (where '<BASE>' is from 1st command).  Then copy the `.bst` into the bst branch, and the `.sty` into the sty branch.

Comment: @jon Do I do this in Terminal on OS X (Mac)? I copied the first command in and it seemed to accept it, but it didn't accept the second. Am I meant to amend the '<BASE>' thing?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use biblatex and biber, not bibtex: the main reasons being that 1) biber understands utf8 encoding, so that accented characters, greek, arabic or chinese will not be a problem; 2) biblatex is much easier to customise (if necessary) than bibtex, as it uses latex-style commands, unlike bibtex, which has a language of its own that uses reverse polish notation.

Your document, as regards the bibliography commands, should contain these lines (for an author-year style; and first names initialised):

```
\documentclass{article}
.......................
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, firstinits]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{name_of_the_bibfile.bib}
.......................

\begin{document}
.......................
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I supposed you want one bibliography, at the end of your essay. But with biblatex, you can have multiple bibliographies, bibliographies with sections, &c.

The simplest way to have a correct .bib file in utf8 encoding is to use `JabRef`, which provides a convenient interface and will warn you if something goes wrong  on filling the different fields. Don't forget to choose the encoding (it's not utf8 by default) via Options -> Preferences -> General.

Comment: Thanks Bernard. So if I wanted to use lsalike instead of authoryear, I'd just do a straight swap? Where should lsalike be on my system in order for it to find it?

I'll give this a go when I get a chance and get back to you if I'm still stuck!

Comment: I don't know: never heard of it (I'm not a specialist of bib style files). With biblatex, it goes through .bbx files, not .bst's So just swapping supposes there exists an isalike.bbx file (and an isalike.cbx for citations, if you use them). As far as I know, it doesn'exist, so it should be created, mainly starting from one of the existing basic styles (`alphabetic`, `author-year`, `author-title`, `numeric`) and adding a few commands/patches to modify the output where necessary.

Comment: I have no idea how you would do that, so would I need to use natbib/BibTeX in the absence of .bbx and .cbx files?

Comment: I could help if I knew what's required. Biblatex has a natbib emulation mode. Where did you find these files?

Comment: just a heads up ... if you are intending to submit what you write to a particular publisher, do check on what that publisher requests.  it may be that what you find most convenient is *not* what the publisher can use, and the reason is *not* sheer cussedness, but the fact that in order to meet deadlines and produce journals that look consistent, certain procedures have been set up, and it is possible to change those procedures only glacially.  sad but true.

Comment: @andylaw31 -- If you really mean this, "I want to use a special bibliography style called `lsalike`", which comes with a `.bst`, you *cannot* use `biblatex` until someone translates that style into something `biblatex` understands.  As much as I recommend `biblatex` generally, you might consider sticking with 'plain' BibTeX as long as you need/want to use that style.

Comment: @andylaw31: this link: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71567/how-can-i-number-the-references-in-a-bibliography-irrespective-of-their-order-of might be of interest.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Not intending to submit, just following their conventions with regards to the bibliography.

Comment: @jon Thanks - that clarifies things!

Comment: @Bernard Thanks! Looks like they have given an example of how you would use lsalike. Just need to know where to store it now I think.

Comment: They must be in a LocalTeXMF directory (if you use TeXLive, it already exists – not sure of the exact name; for MiKTeX, you'll have to create one and declare it to MiKTeX Settings as a personal root). The lsa.bst file must go in LocalTeXMF\bibtex\bst\lsa\ and lsa.sty in  LocalTeXMF\tex\latex\lsa\. Don't forget to run texhash (TeXLive) ot Refresh FNDB (MiKTeX).

Comment: I second the recommendation to use ``biblatex``, but be aware that virtually no journals which accept submissions in TeX format use it. They all use ``BibTeX``.

Comment: @ Sverre: Is it also a problem if the backend is BibTeX?